# Setting up 301 redirects for multiple domains merging to single domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I've got a tricky situation where four different websites are now merging into a single site. I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle 301 redirects for old URLs from these sites.

Here's an example for illustration. Say I have these four sites:

```
https://red.com
https://blue.com
https://green.com
https://magenta.com
```

And they're all now going to be living just at `https://red.com`.

Each of these sites had a "Team" page...

```
https://red.com/team/
https://blue.com/team/
etc.
```

Once I've pointed all the URLs to the same place, I'd like to see if someone tried to enter one of the previous URLs, and direct them to a specific new place on the site, e.g.:

```
URL Entered: https://blue.com/team/
301 Redirect: https://red.com/blue/team/

URL Entered: https://green.com/team/
301 Redirect: https://red.com/green/team/

etc.
```

Since folks may be coming from multiple different domains, I can't use standard relative 301 redirects in .htaccess for this. I'd like to just be able to point the DNS for these other domains to go straight to `red.com`, and then handle the 301 redirect logic there.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: You can use a RewriteCond to extract the part before the dot from the host name. (You’d have to be careful though, if domains such as `foo.co.uk` could also be relevant here - if you don’t want to redirect those to `https://red.com/foo.co/team/` accordingly, but have just `foo` in there - then you will have to develop a logic that is a little more complex.)

Comment: Got it! Does this generally look right? 
```# Blue team page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.blue.com$
Redirect 301 /team https://red.com/blue/team/

# Green team page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.green.com$
Redirect 301 /team https://red.com/green/team/

# Default team page
Redirect 301 /team https://red.com/team/``` 
(I can't really test this yet, because I haven't pointed the DNS for these domains yet. Also, the redirects here are simplified and will involve more subdirectories and different names than the original domains, so I don't need to worry about the foo.co example.)

Comment: You’ll have to use RewriteRules to do the actual redirects, only those are affected by RewriteCond, they don’t work on the Redirect directive.

Comment: Oh, okay! More like this, then? `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.blue.com$`
 `RewriteRule "^/team$" "https://red.com/blue/team/" [R]`

Comment: Yeah, something like that. The dots inside the pattern should be escaped, otherwise they mean any arbitrary character (though unlikely to occur in this particular situation maybe.) But instead of such a condition-rule-combination for every single domain, I was more thinking of something like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([a-z0-9-]+)\.com$ RewriteRule "^team$" "https://red.com/$1/team/" [R]` (That’s why I mentioned that stuff like `foo.co.uk` might extra treatment then.)

Comment: Oh and when rewriting is configured in .htaccess context, the path RewriteRule matches against never starts with a /, that has been stripped off at that point already  - so `^/team$` should never match, it needs to be `^team$`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `302 temporary redirect` rather than using 301 which is permanent.

** Also don't forget to clear previous 301 redirection caches on your web browser; if used.